# Save last object value in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Given my lack of experience I'm not sure it's a problem with Vue.js or javascript.
Basically I'm trying to save the value of an object before it is modified and then eventually restore it.
But I think I collide with the data binding, I use two objects:

```
this.filters
this.myFilters

retrieve () {
  this.filters = this.myFilters ? this.myFilters : this.filters
}
```

But this.myFilters updates in parallel with this.filters.

I do not know where to orientate myself

Answer (score 1):

Assigning directly only copies the reference... its just another variable referring to the same object.

You will have to `clone` the object. Check out some JS object cloning tutorials or questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: thank you very much for the inspiration, I managed to solve with `this.myFilters = Object.assign ({}, this.filters)`